# concatenate datetime with string

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

i am getting an error when trying to concatenate date and string.

```
declare @select varchar(max) 
declare @where varchar(max)
set @select = 'select * from tbl Emp........'
@where = ' where Emp.date >='+ cast((cast(getdate() as date)) as varchar(20))
exec(@select+@where)
```

I also tried to do like below but didn't work:

```
declare @today varchar(20)
@today = cast((cast(getdate() as date))
@where = 'where Emp.date> =' + '@today'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like this...

```
declare @select varchar(max) 
declare @where varchar(max)
set @select = 'select * from tbl Emp '
set @where = ' where Emp.date >= ''' + CONVERT(varchar(8),getdate(),112) + ''''

exec(@select+@where)
```

Or an even better option would be something like this.....

```
DECLARE @Sql nvarchar(max);
DECLARE @Date DATE = GETDATE();

SET @Sql = N' select * from tbl Emp '
         + N' where Emp.date >= @Date'

Exec sp_executesql @Sql
                  ,N'@Date DATE'
                  ,@Date
```

But why do you even need dynamic sql for this simple query why cant you simply do

```
DECLARE @Date DATE = GETDATE();

select * from tbl Emp
where Emp.date >= @Date
```

Comment: @sanmah, you also need the quotes suggested by the answer to get the correct results don't you?

Comment: @ala, when i concatenate where with cast() statement, it worked fine without quotes...